# EF delete order

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have the following entities structure-
ParameterDefinition-->ParameterGroup-->Parameter
ParameterDefinition-->ParameterOperations

Also there is a map table with 2 FKs- Parameter & ParameterOperation (many to many entity).
The problem is that when i try to delete ParameterDefinition it first tries to delete ParameterGroup which can't be done because FK constraint to Parameter.

All my associations are set On Delete- Cascade.

How can i solve this so first it will start from the Map Entity , than other entities according the FKs ?

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've read, you have to both set your FKs in the database to cascade on delete.  The EDMX file won't pick this up when you update it, so you also have to set cascade on delete on the FKs in the EDMX file.  Did you set the cascade on delete option at both the database level and the EDMX level?  I'm reading it as you've only done this at the EDMX level, but I could be wrong.

I'm not a big fan of setting all my FKs to cascade on delete, so I just had to delete things in the correct order.

Comment: I set On Delete Cascade on all FK . I don't know what to set on the Map Table. I set on one of the FKs On delete cascade but now i get the EF exception- Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.